# how to write jqpl sentence in java jpa

Tags: mysql, jpa, netbeans, jpql

i have the following scene:

I have two tables, table Publication and table Order. A Publication has an Order and Order has a field call active that can be 0 or 1.
Obviously my entity Publication has a list of Orders.

I want to get from my database all the publications with their Order list, but I want only the orders that has active = 1. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Next time you should at least provide what have you tried so far and why it didn't work.

Comment: i dont know how to do ir, i dont tried anything

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
SELECT *
FROM Publication AS p, `Order` AS o
WHERE (p.ordernum = o.ordernum) AND (o.active = 1);
```

Assuming that both tables have a ordernum field which estabilishes the relationship between both.

P.S.: Mind the `` around Order, it's a reserved word so they are necessary.

Comment: I need jpql sintaxis not only SQL.
If i do that i thinks is not going to work, because im selecting de publications and when a publication has an order with active 0 and another with active 1 its going to bring me the publiaction with the two orders.
I tried that but i have a big error when i getResultList from query and i dont know what is it.